# (Any) folder listener for UWP Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I need to access random folders somewhere on my local filesystem.

UWP normally has no access to them and the approach with setting "broadFileSystemAccess" does not work sadly.

What would be a good approach to access those folders and the files within in my UWP App? I thought about writing a small WPF App that copies those files from the random folder into a folder that my UWP App would have access to.

**Edit**: The problem with this is, that I want to set the path once on a new device and it should keep the access for the folder even after reboot. Is that possible with the FilePicker solution? I managed to get the broadFileSystemAccess to work but the problem here is, that on every device you need to enable that first manually for this app. Sadly that is not an option, because this app will run on many customer devices.

I am thankful for any kind of advice.

Kind regards

Comment: "UWP normally has no access to them and the approach with setting "broadFileSystemAccess" does not work sadly." You have to explain it. It is like saying that UWP doesn't work or even Windows doesn't work. It works, maybe you are looking for some hidden folders but you haven't mentioned that, as written above this isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FileOpenPicker` to access local location, for example, useing FileOpenPicker access `PictureLibrary`. For more information about FileOpenPicke, you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#file-picker-ui).

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
    this.textBlock.Text = "Picked photo: " + file.Name;
}
else
{
    this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
}
```

I don’t know how you use `broadFileSystemAccess` capability and causes this unexpected behaivor. Generally, `broadFileSystemAccess` capabilities can make you be able to access folders using `StorageFolder()` API, for example:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"D:\test.txt");
```

For more information about accessing additional locations, you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)

**update**

There is a way to access local location. You can use `MRU` and `Future-access list`. For example, use `FileOpenPicker` to get a file and save this file to `Future-access list` and `MRU`:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
string mruToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "20120716");
string faToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
```

For more information about `MRU` and `Future-access list`, you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders).

Comment: The problem with this is, that I want to set the path once on a new device and it should keep the access for the folder even after reboot. Is that possible with the FilePicker solution? I managed to get the broadFileSystemAccess to work but the problem here is, that on every device you need to enable that first manually for this app. Sadly that is not an option, because this app will run on many customer devices.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Do I still have access to the folder after reboot (maybe in the meantime the folder did get more files that I need to read) or will it just copy the files in my app once at the start? I will check out the document that you linked.

Comment: @Johnny `FileOpenPicker` needs to pick the file again after reboot. The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is more convenient because it only needs to be set once. And it still also accesses anywhere in the file system whether your computer reboot or not. After reboot, the `future-access list` has permission to access the files that are saved before the reboot, but it only saves storage files, not storage folders.